# How to make sure that message control id of BTAHL7 ACK Message is same as original mesage

Tags: biztalk, hl7, biztalk-2013, btahl7

We have a requirement that the Message Control Id (MSH.10) of the HL7 ACK message should be equal to the message control id (MSH.10) of the original message. We are using BTAHL7 with BizTalk 2013 R2, CU5. In our case at present, the message control id of ACK is actually a permutation of the original message's message control id. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer: **don't even try**.  This is not standard HL7.

The ref value is in MSA02 per HL7.

*This is not a problem with HL7 or BizTalk Server.*  This is a problem created by your Trading Partner.

If this is being pushed by a Trading Partner, **the first response is simply NO**, because this is not standard HL7.

If they keep pushing this, your next step is to inform your management that because the Trading Partner is requiring non standard HL7, it will take you **a lot of extra time and money to support this**.  You will need a completely custom numbering scheme.

Comment: Hi Johns, First of all, thanks a lot for your reply. I checked your profile and I assume you have extremely good knowledge in BizTalk. So my query to you is more from the point of getting a guidance from you. The client did send us a couple of links that shows Original Message's MSH.10 = ACK MSH10. How do we convince the client otherwise?

Comment: Are you sure the samples weren't just coincidence?  If they have to test systems that start at 1, the Control ID will *appear* to by synchronized, but they are not.  How do you convince them?  First, by politely telling them that not how HL7 works, there is no requirement to synchronize those ID.  X12 and EDIFACT have similar ID that do no require synchronization.,

Comment: Here a nice description of MSH10.  It makes no reference to returning the originating Message ID.  http://www.hl7resources.com/Public/index.html?a55433.htm

Comment: This is the correct answer. The same issue was recently discussed on the HL7 Infrastructure and Messaging mailing list so see these messages for an explanation on why the requirement is wrong. http://lists.hl7.org/read/messages?id=307612

Comment: Dear John. I also found one more link do check [link](https://www.hl7.org/documentcenter/public_temp_C7436319-1C23-BA17-0C438CDDE7B88F46/wg/conf/HL7MSH.htm) section **2.24.1.10 Message control ID (ST) 00010**. Thanks again for your support. Really appreciate it.

Comment: The biggest problem with this is the Trading Partner is dictating how you generate unique ID's.  This is entirely inappropriate.  You own your HL7 system, not the trading Partner.  And as noted, it's non-standard.